# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. How to include correctly?

Tags: c, include

I have the following files:

**bst.h**: which just contains the declarations

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    unsigned int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

int insert(Node *node);
Node* lookup(unsigned int key);
int delete(Node *node);
```

**bst.c**: which defines the declarations

```
#include "bst.h"

#include <stdio.h>


Node *root = NULL;

int insert(Node* node) {
    ... implementation ...
    return 0;
}

Node* lookup(unsigned int key) {
    ... implementation ...
    return current;
}

int delete(Node *node) {
    ... implementation ...
    return 0;
}
```

**test_bst.c**: which tests the BST implementation

```
#include "bst.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    Node node = {10,NULL,NULL};

    insert(&node);

    return 0;
}
```

If i run `gcc test_bst.c` i get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_insert", referenced from:
      _main in cc1m0mA1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong here? Does it have to do with the way I include files? Or with my compilation instruction? I saw a lot of questions with the same title as mine - however, none of them was helpful to resolve my error.

Comment: You need to compile both C files.

Comment: Add `extern` to function signatures in header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't include the file where you actually implement the `insert` function. You can do something like:

```
gcc -c -o bst.o bst.c
gcc -o test test_bst.c bst.o
```

Comment: First line's wrong - it'll try to link an executable.

Comment: Thanks, compiling both worked: 
gcc -o bst_test test_bst.c bst.c

Comment: @ndrizza: That works, too :) Point is that if your project grows and you get hundreds  of .c files, compiling them one by one might make the process much more manageable, because you will only have to recompile the files you changed and then link them together.